# Trying to remember the name of a sci-fi actioner from around the late 80s-early 90s

Tags: story-identification, computers, cyberpunk, cryogenics

Here's what I recall about it:

Notorious criminals have their consciousness pulled out of their bodies, after which the body is frozen and the mind is locked up in a super secure cyber-prison. Big Bad Guy's friends hack into the prison and pull out his consciousness, which takes the form of a glowing blue energy person in the real world. To have a functioning body, he goes into some kind of rubber-spraying chamber and gets a layer of the stuff over his blue energy. He eventually kills a guy with it, by pushing him into the chamber and spraying rubber over him until the guy suffocates.

He eventually tries to go get his body out of cryo, but the Big Good Guy gets to it first and puts a couple of bullets through its head. Bad Guy is mad.

Bad Guy can also reach through the Internet, put his energy hand through a person's computer monitor and shock them to death.

The Good Guy eventually also turns himself into an energy being, they have a fight, Good Guy wins.

Don't know the exact year, country or anything... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Based on the descriptions, I assume this is a film rather than a book?

Comment: Indeed, Sean. I don't remember if it was a feature film, TV production or miniseries... but it was something video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Big Bad Guy was a dreadlocked tan body builder in a white bodysuit then *[Hologram Man](http://cybertronicmovies.blogspot.com/2011/03/hologram-man.html)* (1995) is your answer.

[image]

Violent & crazy (best combo) Slash Gallagher is arrested by cop Kurt Decoda then sentenced to "Holographic Stasis". His body is put into stasis, while his mind is adjusted. Slash's gang of cyber criminals break him out, but his body is destroyed in the attempt. Slash is rendered an energy hologram digital body. Lots of early 1990 special effects, big explosions, tough guy one liners and bigger explosions. Your energy hand through monitor to electrocute is there.

Comment: OH MY GAD YES!!! You got it jjskellie! This movie was so bad, and I have never needed anything more in my life... Thank you so much!

Comment: When I look at that poster, all I see is Paul Walker vs. The Undertaker.